# Why the second time I hover on an element it disappears?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a code that, when you hover an span for some seconds, a box appears and if you keep your mouse on the box, it stand still without fading out again. The sample code is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>I'm a pathetic programmer please don't flame me</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var b = 1000;
            var c = $('#box');
            var d = function(a) {
                if (a) {
                    c.fadeOut(500)
                } else {
                    c.fadeIn(500)
                }
            };
            $('span').mouseenter(function() {
                e = setTimeout(function() {
                    d()
                }, b);
                $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                    typeof e != 'undefined' && clearTimeout(e);
                    f = setTimeout(function() {
                        d(1)
                    }, 300)
                })
            });
            c.mouseenter(function() {
                clearTimeout(f);
                typeof g != 'undefined' && clearTimeout(g)
            }).mouseleave(function() {
                g = setTimeout(function() {
                    d(1)
                }, 300)
            })
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #box {
            display: none;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<span>HOVER ME</span>
<div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** JS fiddle for live test: http://jsfiddle.net/2ogcp9tm/

Problem is that the code works fine the first time I run it but if I hover the span for a second time and I try to put my mouse on the blue box, it disappears anyway.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please don't post minified code -- use meaningful variable names, not a, b, c, ...

Comment: @Barmar te original var were worst, so I did this because it's more clearful than use variables written in a foreign language.

Comment: Good point, those are pretty annoying, too. :) But sometimes we can make sense of them, while a, b, c, is totally confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you enter a `span`, you bind a `mouseleave` handler for that span. So if you enter a span multiple times, when you leave it you'll run the `mouseleave` handler multiple times. Each of these will call `setTimeout()`, but `f` will only be set to the last one. So when you later do `clearTimeout(f)`, it only clears one of them, the others continue to run.

It's almost never right to bind one event handler inside another event handler. Event handlers should usually be defined at the top level. If you want one handler to be dependent on whether some other handler has run first, use a variable to keep track of it.

Answer (score 1):

You hang `.mouseleave()` event handler every time `mouseenter` is triggered for `span`, creating multiple event handlers for same event, which results in triggering all these handlers, making `mouseleave` logic incorrect (setting multiple timeouts and rewriting `f` variable).

`.mouseleave()` should be rewritten in something like this:

```
var e;

$('span').mouseenter(function() {
    e = setTimeout(function() {
        d()
    }, b);
});

$('span').mouseleave(function() {
    typeof e != 'undefined' && clearTimeout(e);
    f = setTimeout(function() {
        d(1)
    }, 300)
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ogcp9tm/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this : [click here for jsfiddle working code](http://jsfiddle.net/2ogcp9tm/4/)

Old Code:

```
       $('span').mouseenter(function() {
            e = setTimeout(function() {
                d()
            }, b);
            $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                typeof e != 'undefined' && clearTimeout(e);
                f = setTimeout(function() {
                    d(1)
                }, 300)
            })
        });
```

New Code:

```
        $('span').mouseenter(function() {
            e = setTimeout(function() {
                d()
            }, b);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            typeof e != 'undefined' && clearTimeout(e);
            f = setTimeout(function() {
                d(1)
            }, 300)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
        var b = 1000;
        var c = $('#box');
        var d = function(a) {
            if (a) {
                c.fadeOut(500)
            } else {
                c.fadeIn(500)
            }
        };
        $('span').mouseenter(function() {
            e = setTimeout(function() {
                d()
            }, b);
        });
            $('#box').mouseenter(function() {
            e = setTimeout(function() {
                d()
            }, b);
            $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                typeof e != 'undefined' && clearTimeout(e);
                f = setTimeout(function() {
                    d(1)
                }, 300)
            })
        });
        c.mouseenter(function() {
            clearTimeout(f);
            typeof g != 'undefined' && clearTimeout(g)
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            g = setTimeout(function() {
                d(1)
            }, 300)
        })
    });
```

And here's the JSFiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/2ogcp9tm/3/

Comment: You had an event whereby the box would fade out on the `mouseleave` from `span`. Since the `div` is an entirely different entity, entering that `div` would trigger `mouseleave` function. In the update I just posted, the `mouseleave` is instead binding to `div`. This way, the box shows when you hover `span` and doesn't leave again until you `mouseleave` the `div`